# show products in view when there are inside JSON/ OBJ using Nativeescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript, object, nativescript

I have this JSON:

```
{
    "StatusCode": 0,
    "StatusMessage": "OK",
    "StatusDescription": [
        {
            "pharmacy_id": "011E752345553380ABC13FFA163ECD15",
            "pharmacy_name": "Pharmacy",
            "lastUpdated": "2019-12-03T11:15:26.510Z",
            "products": [
                {
                    "productID": "11AA016CBEFFE8B29B46E8393535C49F",
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "product_name": "BETADINE",
                    "price": 10
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "pharmacy_id": "011E762345552280FBC13FFA163ECD10",
            "pharmacy_name": "Test Pharmacy",
            "lastUpdated": "2019-12-03T13:40:55.759Z",
            "products": [
                {
                    "productID": "11BA016CBEFFE8B29B46E8393445C49F",
                    "quantity": 4,
                    "product_name": "EUCARBON",
                    "price": 10
                },
                {
                    "productID": "11BA016CBEFFE8B29B46E8393532C49F",
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "product_name": "ALMACINE",
                    "price": 10
                },
                {
                    "productID": "22BA016CBEFFE8B29B46E8393555C49F",
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "product_name": "BUPRENORFIN",
                    "price": 10
                }
            ],
        },
          .....

    ]
}
```

I want to show in view product_name, quantity, price.

I get all data from API with this code:

```
public items: Receta;
    getall() {
        this.WS.history().subscribe(
            items => {
                this.items = items;
                console.log('itemsssssssssssssss', items) // show JSON
                console.log('itemsssssssssssssss.products', items.products) // show undefined
            },
            err => console.error('err', err),
            () => console.log('error')
        );     
    }
```

In html I can show only pharmacy_name, I want to show and products for each pharmacy .

```
   <StackLayout *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;" padding="10">
                        <GridLayout columns="*" rows="auto" style="padding: 10%;">
                            <Label [text]="item .pharmacy_name" class="list-group-item-heading"
                                style="width: 60%; font-size: 14px; text-align: left;" row="0" col='0'
                                horizontalAlignment="left"></Label>
                        </GridLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

Please, can you ask me any idea how to show  and products in view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is here:

```
console.log('itemsssssssssssssss.products', items.products) // show undefined
```

There are no products in your `items` JSON

You need to do something like this

```
const newItemsArray = [];
items.StatusDescription.forEach((st) => {
     newItemsArray = newItemsArray.concat(st.products);
})
```

Now the newItemsArray, will have all the products in it. You can use the `rxjs` `map` operator, to return this array.

Or you could have the newItemsArray as a public member of your class and use it directly.

```
   <StackLayout *ngFor="let item of newItemsArray ; let i = index;" padding="10">
                        <GridLayout columns="*" rows="auto" style="padding: 10%;">
                            <Label [text]="item .pharmacy_name" class="list-group-item-heading"
                                style="width: 60%; font-size: 14px; text-align: left;" row="0" col='0'
                                horizontalAlignment="left"></Label>
                        </GridLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

To access the products you need another ngFor like this

```
  <StackLayout *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;" padding="10">
                        <GridLayout columns="*" rows="auto" style="padding: 10%;">
                            <Label *ngFor="let product of item.products; let i = index;" [text]="product.product_name" class="list-group-item-heading"
                                style="width: 60%; font-size: 14px; text-align: left;" row="0" col='0'
                                horizontalAlignment="left"></Label>
                        </GridLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: I have this `public items: Receta;` When I write like you say      `items = items.concat(st.products);`  Property 'concat' does not exist on type 'Receta'.ts(2339)

Comment: Sorry, I used the same name with the existing object.

Comment: Yes, but I want to show pharmacy_name, and products from pharmacy, not only products. `console.log(newItemArray)` show only products

Comment: Ok, you can access the products from your initial structure, by adding another `*ngFor` as shown in the updated answer.